# ZSH and Git autocompletion: Same configuration, different behaviors

Tags: macos, ubuntu, git, zsh, autocomplete

I've searched Google/Super User for a while and I couldn't find any problemas similar to what's happening to me, so I decided to ask a question.

My problem is the following: I have the same zsh/prompt/autocomplete configuration in two different machines: One running OSX and one running Ubuntu 17.04 (a VPS on digital ocean).

Most of the things works exactly the same, except for git autocompletion, as you can see from:

[image: this screenshot]

As you can see, the top window (macOS) shows little options to complete, while the bottom window (Ubuntu) shows all my aliases and stuff.

My question is: does anyone knows why this happens? Any idea on how I can fix it or how can I debug both of them to find where things go wrong in Mac?

Some more info:

```
macOS Version: 10.12.4
Zsh Version: zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
Git Version: git version 2.12.2

Ubuntu Version: 17.04
Zsh Version: zsh 5.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)
Git Version: git version 2.11.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478673/how-to-show-zsh-function-definition-like-bash-type-myfunc) question where people mentioned the `whence -v` command.

Running `whence -v _git` (zsh completions functions usually follow the pattern `_<command_name>`), I've got two different results:

Ubuntu

```
$ whence -v _git
_git is an autoload shell function
```

macOS

```
$ whence -v git
_git is a shell function from /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
```

Since I've installed `git` via Brew on my mac, `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git` was a symlink to the brew completion file. I've deleted the symlink, reload my shell with `exec zsh` and everything worked as expected.

After that, I've removed `git` and reinstalled it without the completions:

```
brew remove git
brew install git --without-completions
```

And everything is working as expected!